# help designing a method, should I use out or ref or return the type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that I will use in the following contexts:

1.

User user = null;

```
if(...)
{
      user = defaultUser;
      SetUser(a,b,user);
}
else
{
      SetUser(a,b,user);
}

SaveUser(user);
```

So some cases are where user may be null, while in other cases it will already be initialized.

How should I design the SetUser method?

**I currently have it like so, but this causes an error when user is null.**

```
public void SetUser(object a, object b, User user)
{
     if(user == null)
         user = new User();

     user.Security = a.security;
     user.Blah = b.type;
}
```

Comment: note that I added the call to SaveUser(user);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither. Just return it:

```
public User SetUser(object a, object b, User user) {
  if (user == null) {
     user = new User();
  }
  user.Security = a.security;
  user.Blah = b.type;
  return user;
}
```

Send in a user object or null, and assign the result to the reference:

```
User user;
if(...) {
  user = SetUser(a, b, defaultUser);
} else {
  user = SetUser(a, b, null);
}
SaveUser(user);
```

Note that you have to create a new `defaultUser` instance each time you use it, as it will become the new user object. If you try to reuse the default user object, you will end up overwriting previous user objects and also end up with several references to the same object instead of separate objects.

Comment: +1 Using out/ref parameters when a single return type is all that is needed is definite code smell.

Answer (score 2):

`user` has to be **ref**. Otherwise the assignment of a `new User()` to the local `user` does not affect the caller's `user`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SetUser(object a, object b, User user)
```

this will not work anyway because you modify local (parameter variable).

Rule is simple - use out/ref if you want to return **more** than one value.